# Even holomorphic function on the punctured disk has a primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $\{z|0<|z|<1\}$, and $f$ is even.

I need to show that f has a primitive. Any ideas?

Comment: Now what, odd or even?

Comment: Even, sorry fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f$ in the form of Laurent series around $0$. You get the form $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$. Now, if we prove that $a_{-1}=0$ then $F(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$ is a primitive function of $f$. So we just have to prove that $a_{-1}=0$ and we are done. And here we are going to use that $f$ is even. We know that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n=f(z)=f(-z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(-z)^n$. So if we define $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$ then $g$ is the zero function and its Laurent expansion is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$. Because Laurent expansion is unique we conclude that $a_{2n+1}=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $a_{-1}=0$.

Comment: How can we take Laurent series around 0, if 0 is not in our domain?

Comment: The origin is a singular point so you can take Laurent series around it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a primitive of $f\restriction_{\Bbb D\setminus(-\infty,0]}$. Then $z\mapsto F(z)+F(-z)$ is constant where defined, i..e, constant on the upper half disk and constant on the lower half disk. Clearly, the constants are negatives of each other. By adding a suitable constant to $F$, we can achieve that $F(z)+F(-z)=0$ thoughout, i.e., $F$ is odd. If we defien $F(z)=-F(-z)$ on $(-1,0)$, we obtain a continuos (and necesarily holomorphic) function on the whole punctured disk.

Comment: I am not sure it is constant on the lower and upper half disc. the opration $z \rightarrow -z$ is symetric relatively to the line $y=-x$, right?

Comment: @user3708158 The derivative of $F(z)+F(-z)$ is $f(z)-f(-z)$. As the latter is $=0$, the former is locally constant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0 < r < 1$. Then we have
$$\int_{\partial B_r(0)} f(z)\, dz = 
\int_0^{2\pi} f(re^(it)ire^{it}\, dt
=  \int_0^{\pi} f(re^{it})ire^{it}\, dt + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f(re^{it})ire^{it}\, dt.$$
For the second integal we have
$$ \int_\pi^{2\pi} f(re^{it})ire^{it}\, dt
=  \int_0^{\pi} f(re^{i(t+ \pi)})ire^{i(t+ \pi) }\, dt
=  -\int_0^{\pi} f(-re^{it})ire^{it }\, dt=
-\int_0^{\pi} f(re^{it})ire^{it }\, dt,$$
by the evenness of $f$. 
By homotopy, every simple loop avoiding 0 integrates to 0.   Now pick a any point $z_0$ in the punctured disk.  Define $F(z) = \int_\gamma f(z)\, dz,$
where $\gamma$ is a path connecting $z_0$ to $z$.  This is well-defined because of the fact for that every loop in the punctured disk, the integral along the loop integrates to zero.

Comment: That is $f$ even implies $f(z)dz$ is odd $1$-form : $f(-z)d(-z) = -f(z)dz$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part from: "By homotopy, every...." ?
I don't think that the punctured disk is a simply connected set.

Comment: It is not.  See John Conway's Complex Variables for this connection.  It is very cool.